# How do I take full values from shuffled foreach? I need to generate a unique alphanumeric code that will also have shuffled pattern

Tags: php

```
$num = range('0', '9');
$alpha = range('A','Z');

$num[mt_rand(0, 9)];
$alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)];

$res = array($num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)], $num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)]);
shuffle($res);

foreach($res as $rand){
    $result = $rand;
}

echo $result;
```

I wanted to generate alphanumeric code that also changes pattern(ex. D8M4, 23EH, 4OP4). But when I try to take the `$result` outside the foreach, it only displays one random number of letter. How can I achieve this random alphanumeric code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) function, instead of foreach.

```
<?php
    $num = range('0', '9');
    $alpha = range('A','Z');

    $num[mt_rand(0, 9)];
    $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)];

    $res = array($num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)], $num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)]);
    shuffle($res);

    echo implode($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add each character / number to an array and implode at the end.

```
    $num = range('0', '9');
    $alpha = range('A','Z');

    $num[mt_rand(0, 9)];
    $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)];

    $res = array( $num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)], $num[mt_rand(0, 9)], $alpha[mt_rand(0, 25)] );
    shuffle( $res );

    foreach( $res as $rand ) $result[] = $rand;
    echo implode( '',$result );
```